# Protractor filter elements that dont have a specific child

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am trying to filter out elements within an ElementArrayFinder using the .filter() function. I have had success using it to filter elements by checking that a specific child exists, but cannot do the reverse. Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="krn_event krn_event_line0" unselectable="on" style="position: absolute; left: 477px; top: 161px; width: 84px; height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
<div unselectable="on" class="krn_event_inner">
    <div class="entity  advanced-renderer" id="shift_20111">  
        <span class="entity-title">9:00 AM - 7:00 PM</span> 
        <div class="entity-segments entity-type-shift">      
            <div class="entity-segment type-break" style="left:40%; width:5%"> </div>       
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="krn_event krn_event_line0" unselectable="on" style="position: absolute; left: 58px; top: 236px; width: 71px; height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;">
<div unselectable="on" class="krn_event_inner">
    <div class="entity  advanced-renderer" id="shift_20121">
        <span class="entity-title">7:00 AM - 3:30 PM</span> 
        <div class="entity-segments entity-type-shift">
            <div class="entity-segment type-break" style="left:47%; width:5%"></div>
            <div class="entity-segment type-transfer" style="left:52%; width:48%"></div>
            <div class="entity-icons">
                <i class="entity-icon icon-k-transfer"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am looking for only elements like the first block, that do not contain a '.entity-segment type-transder' div element. Unfortunately, a loop wouldn't work since I would need to resolve promises of isPresent() or .$$().count(). Here is what I have so far using the .filter() function:

```
regShifts = shifts.filter(function(elem){
          return elem.$('[class="entity-segment type-transfer"]').isPresent().then(function (ans){
            return ans === false;
          });
        });
```

Where shifts is a list of all shifts on the page. Could someone point me in the right direction or tell me whats going wrong here? When this code runs the test waits and the entire test fails with a FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory. It also provides the 'Last few GCs' and JS stacktrace info. Thanks

Edit: Forgot to ask, is there a .not() function that I could incorporate into here? I know of EC.not() but that only works with browser functions I believe. I did some research on CSS selectors and tried using :not() but I could not get it to work.

There are two approaches I have, to filter out the elements I don't want and end up with an array of all usable elements. Or, to check if the element (shift) I selected has the child element, if it does then choose a different shift. The latter seems harder since its difficult to implement loops with promises. Any help you guys have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using element.all(by.css(.....)) or $$('....) instead. Then use the count() to check if it is equal to 0...

Comment: I have tried using .$$() and .count() instead of .isPresent() in the filter function but it returns the same errors

Comment: You can get these type of shifts directly with xpath - "//div[@class='entity-segment type-transfer']//ancestor::div[@class='krn_event krn_event_line0']"

Comment: I am looking for the other shifts that don't contain the descendant '.entity-segment type-transfer'. Is there a not() function or something in xpath i could use to select all those that don't contain '.entity-segment type-transfer'?

Comment: With NOT -- //div[@class='krn_event krn_event_line0' and not(descendant::div[@class='entity-segment type-transfer'])]

Comment: With COUNT -- "//div[@class='krn_event krn_event_line0' and count(descendant::div[@class='entity-segment type-transfer'])=0]"

Comment: Xpath Not line worked great! Thank you so much I had been stuck on this issue for a while and am not very familiar with Xpath/XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're *trying* to get when you say *first block*, buy you can use the `:not()` css with Protractor. Something like...

```
$$('.entity-segment:not(.type-transfer');
```

This assumes you're expecting multiple matches (`$$`), but if not, use the `$` css selector.